# jQuery ajax load issue with parameters to MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

**Introduction**

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 with WebApi 2.0 and jQuery.

**Problem**

I am trying to display a modal with user details comming from a ajax call.
Using `$.getJSON()` I successfully receive the user details in Json format comming from my WebApi.
Now I want to load html in my modal using a partial view.

I tried using following code but the html does not get loaded.
In my console I see the request and response with the correct data and html.

```
loadItem: function () {
        var $a = $(this);
        var id = $a.attr('data-id');

        $.getJSON(uri_api + '/' + id)
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false
                });

                // Get the partial view to show in modal
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    url: uri_internal + '/getuserdetails',
                    done: function (result) {
                        var $modal = $('#modalUserDetails');
                        $modal.html(result);
                        $modal.modal('show');
                    },
                    fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + err);
                    }
                });
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
            });
    }
```

Then I used another ajax function `.load()` to load the html direcly but now I don't receive anything. Also placing a breakpoint in my controller does not fire and I got an 500 internal server error.

Code I use for my load:

```
$.getJSON(uri_api + '/' + id)
                .done(function (data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false
                    });

                    // Get the partial view to show in modal
                    var $modal = $('#modalUserDetails');
                    $modal.load(
                        uri_internal + '/getuserdetails', { user: JSON.stringify(data) }, function () { }
                    );
                    $modal.modal('show');

                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + err);
                });
```

Where my controller is like:

```
public ActionResult GetUserDetails(User user)
{
     return PartialView(user);
}
```

And the modal html to load the data in:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalUserDetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalUserDetailsLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
```

And the partial view:

```
@model ProsecMdmHelper.Models.User

<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalUserDetailsLabel"><i class="icon-check"></i>Gebruiker details</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <p>User is called @Model.Name</p>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The 500 error:

```
"Invalid JSON primitive" in Ajax processing: user
```

Comment: If yuu want to return a partial view, it needs to be `dataType: 'html',` (not `'json'`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok thanks now the 500 error is gone, but my `user` object is still null. If I use `$.ajax()` then the user is defined

Comment: Not sure I understand what your trying to do. Why do you have a `load()` function inside your `getJSON()` function? And what does `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` return?

Comment: First I get the user json object from my WebApi and then using the load I pass this json object to my partial view to fill in the controls and load the content into my document. I just got it working now, I had to remove the `json.stringify()` arround my data. Thanks!

Comment: In addition, since it already json, all you need is `load('@Url.Action("getuserdetails", "yourControllerName")', data)`

Comment: You are trying to load the `partialview` in modal and so the `modal` content everything will get replaced. **(modal-head, modal-footer)** try to create a `div` inside `modal-body` and `.load` inside that particular `div`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Only the upper div of my modal is in the document, the rest of the html is comming from the partial view

Comment: @Mivaweb.. I feel something really wrong in the way you `show` the modal because you are trying to show modal on `<h4>` tag and the main `modal` contains that `<h4>`!!

Comment: The id of the h4 has `label` at the end, eg `modalUserDetailsLabel`. The id of my modal is `modalUserDetails`