# Bootstrap Modal with Ajax not showing up

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Using a bootstrap modal with Ajax to add a user, but on clicking the link the screen will turn dark but the modal itself doesn't show up, while in the network  `invite` function preview the form shows up, so the controller works.

[image]

The form shows up in the html (console) on the 'add' as well, but supposedly on the wrong place.

[image]

When clicked on this link:

```
<a>
<span class="sidebar-text">{{ trans('common.projects') }}
    ({{ count($projectsNav) }})</span> <span class="  pull-right">  <i
            href="/user/invite"
            class="fa fa-cog nopadding" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#modal-basic"
            style="padding: none !important;"></i>
</span>
</a>
```

It should trigger this:

**JavaScript**

```
// Support for AJAX loaded modal window.
// Focuses on first input textbox after it loads the window.
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
        $(url).modal('open');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/user/invite",
            headers: AjaxHeader,
            method: "POST",

            success: function (response) {
                $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + response + '</div>').modal();
            }
        });
       /* $.post(url, function(data) {
            $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal();
        }).success(function() { $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); });*/
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('user/invite', 'UserController@showInvite');
```

**Controller**

```
public function showInvite(UserTypeController $userType)
{
    $usertypes = $userType->getUsertypes();

    return view('user.invite', compact('usertypes'));
}
```

**Blade/Modal form**

```
<div class="modal fade test" id="modal-basic" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-capitalize">{{trans('common.invite_user')}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label text-capitalize">{{trans('common.email')}}</label>

                            <div class="controls">
                                {!! Form::text('email', null , ["class"=>"form-control col-sm-9" ,"id"=>"email" ,"placeholder" =>
                                trans('common.email') ]) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label text-capitalize">{{trans('common.email')}}</label>

                            <div class="controls">
                                {!!Form::select("usertype_id",  $usertypes , null ,
                                ['data-live-search'=>"true",'class'=>'selectpicker'])!!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            {!! Form::submit( trans('common.invite'), ["class"=>"btn btn-success text-capitalize", "id"=>"inviteUser", "data-dismiss"=>"modal"]) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to remove the `hide` class from your success callback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the modal into your html.
A solution for this would be:

**Step 1**

Add the div modal container directly manual to your html where you would like to ad the modal.

```
<div class="modal hide fade"></div>
```

**Step 2**

Load the modal into your previously created container:

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the partial view to show in modal
    var $modal = $('.modal');
    $modal.load('/user/invite', function() {}); // this will load the returned html into your modal container
    $modal.modal('show'); // show the modal
}
```

**UPDATE**

Remove the outside modal div from your response because you have 2 root `.modal` containers.

Comment: It does load into my HTML (see the edit in post) but supposedly not on the right place. The way I use your code doesn't solve it btw

Comment: No only your `<div class="modal hide fade"></div>` is added into your html, but you can see without any content. if you should place this at the right position then you only need to load the content ( response ) into your container. I had the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975654/jquery-ajax-load-issue-with-parameters-to-mvc-controller

Comment: It does load with contect (see topic edit) but somewhere it is going wrong that the modal does not show up

Comment: Aah ok now I see it, you have a `div.modal` inside another `div.modal` remove the one from your response.

Comment: No problem I have updated my answer with the solution so other ones with the same problem directly see the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
success: function (response) {
    $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + response + '</div>').modal();
}
```

to

```
success: function (response) {
    $(response).modal();
}
```

*cc: see [Mivaweb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3157202/mivaweb)'s  answer*